# Find intersection of 3D convex hull of pointcloud and 2D plane

Tags: python, scipy, geometry

Given a set of points in three dimensional space, e.g. as a numpy array of shape `(n, 3)` where the second dimension encodes the x, y and z coordinates for each point in the pointcloud, I know that I can find its convex hull using `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`.

What I would additionally like to do is obtain the vertices of a two dimensional polygon that describes the cross-section of this convex hull at an arbitrary value of z.

This seems to me like it should be computationally feasible, is there python module which already implements this sort of thing?